# Battlefield 4: Battlelog Android app - Battlescreen : "No connection"

Tags: battlefield-4, battlelog

The battle screen application doesn't seem to work for me.

I get the error, "Battlelog could not find an active game. Please make sure you are connected to the same local network or try the troubleshooting guide."

The troubleshooting guide doesn't help.

I'm running the app on an Asus Memo HD 7".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the release of a major update and expansion pack, the Battlescreen eventually started to work.